# spring boot data jpa can't connect to mysql database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I try to connect to mysql using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and hibernate by [this example](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/) but get

> ...
>   2016-07-28 13:20:49.021 ERROR 7765 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
>   Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type
>   NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on
>   the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are
>   currently active)
>
> ...

application.properties:

```
    # DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database 
# connection. In this example we have "netgloo_blog" as database name and 
# "root" as username and password.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.datasource.username = db
spring.datasource.password = pass

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

project structure in eclipse:

[image]

build.gradle :

```
 buildscript {
  repositories {
        mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-  plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-jpa'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.3' 

   //also tried

    runtime group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.3' 
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.47"

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: I have just created a project with the same configuration and works as expected in Intellij. can you manually launch `./gradlew bootRun` and see what happens?

Comment: there should not be need of diver-class as spring-boot automatically will detect that from `spring.datasource.url`;      

`dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.3'
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not add the driver class

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Check for these dependencies as well

Answer (score 0):

Can you add runtime dependency in gradle as opposed to compile time dependency on the MYSQL Driver jar ?

```
dependencies {
  //compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.3"
  runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.3"
  runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.47"
}
```

Comment: I change build.gradle file by your suggestion but exception still exist. See post.

Answer (score -1):

do you have database driver on the classpath?
have you set property *spring.datasource.driver-class-name*?

For more details, see
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: Yes I have mysql driver, see build.gradle. I added spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver line to application.properties file.